# Logging errors with liquibase update command

Tags: liquibase

I am running liquibase update from command line.
When there is an error, I would like to log the error into a text file.
I tried the --logFile option with update command but it didn't work.
How do I write the liquibase errors into a file?

Thanks,
Radha

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just use the redirect `>` shell command. Like `liquibase update > log.txt`